# array_search() not matching numbers with dots

Tags: php

i make cypher translator. I have an issue with translating encrypted characters ending with dots. I have following dictionary:

```
$dict = array(
     "I"=>"1",
     "L"=>"1.",
     "O"=>"0",
     "Q"=>"0.",
     "Z"=>"2",
     "?"=>"2."
);
```

When I use this:

```
function decode($cypher,$dict){

  $sepp = explode(" ",$cypher);

  foreach($sepp as $char){
    echo array_search($char,$dict);
}}

decode("1. 0. 2.",$dict);
```

I am getting:

```
IOZ
```

Instead of expected:

```
LQ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `array_search` performs the same comparison as the `==` operator, which will attempt to ["type juggle"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) certain values. For instance, `'1' == 1`, `'1.' == 1`, and `'1.' == '1'` are all true.

That means that `'1'` and `'1.'` will always match the same element in your lookup table.

Luckily, the function takes a third argument, which [the manual describes](https://www.php.net/array_search) as:

> If the third parameter `strict` is set to `true` then the `array_search()` function will search for identical elements in the `haystack`. This means it will also perform a strict type comparison of the `needle` in the `haystack`, and objects must be the same instance.

This makes it equivalent to the `===` operator instead. Note that `'1' === 1`, `'1.' === 1`, and `'1.' === '1'` are all false.

So you just need to add that argument:

```
echo array_search($char,$dict,true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to do a strict search.

See 3rd parameter of array_search.

```
function decode($cypher,$dict){

    $sepp = explode(" ",$cypher);

    foreach($sepp as $char){
      echo array_search($char,$dict,true);
    }
}
```

The reason it doesn't work without is because php thinks 1 and 1. is the same number.

Answer (score 1):

This line would help you. Set third parameter to `true`. This causes the comparison to run in strict mode.

`echo array_search($char, $dict, true);`

```
function decode($cypher, $dict)
{
    $sepp = explode(" ",$cypher);
    foreach ($sepp as $char) {
        echo array_search($char, $dict, true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a one-one map, you can just flip your map, and use the array to translate your cipher directly.

```
<?php
$dict = array(
     'I'=>'1',
     'L'=>'1.',
     'O'=>'0',
     'Q'=>'0.',
     'Z'=>'2',
     '?'=>'2.'
);

$cipher = "1. 0. 2.";

$decode = strtr($cipher, array_flip($dict));

var_dump($decode);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "L Q ?"
```